# Google Identity toolkit sned verification code

Tags: google-api, google-identity-toolkit

while integrating identity toolkit send verification code i get response with status 200 but the sms is not sent to the phone number sent to the api request.

```
POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendVerificationCode?key={API_KEY} HTTP/1.1
Host: identitytoolkit.googleapis.com:443
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 39

{
    "phoneNumber": "{PHONE_NUMBER}",
}
```

the response is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Thu, 15 Jun 2023 12:24:09 GMT
Server: ESF
Cache-Control: private
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "sessionInfo": "AL3R4eScaYbcQv8W3BLSK7VhJInR7bxBeWTtGqr1GFYbMAZxA01dFXz71aShRuxDmmJ6D9D5dByTjIAnm29akAq57w93UcbdZH__l5EOcNgu7eEcH6T2nUqs148YCn-qNOyXVLic-T2loIHd1b1q9vnasOwREm_yXg"
}
```